Encountering Oracle APEX Internal Error: APEX.PROCESS.UNHANDLED_ERROR
When I try to switch sessions and register the session using the "apex_custom_auth.post_login" function, I receive the following error message. Has anyone encountered similar issues? I’ve debugged the code for a NO_DATA_FOUND exception, but with no success.
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.PROCESS.UNHANDLED_ERROR
ora_sqlcode: 100
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: no data found
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGES
component.id: 15394000000982
component.name: Register
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 292

How can I determine whether this is an APEX internal error or a PL/SQL code error?
I have tried Oracle APEX debugging techniques and checked for SELECT INTO queries without exceptions.

It's not an apex internal error, it's an "unhandled error". That means that during the processing the APEX engine encountered a NO_DATA_FOUND exception and that exception is not properly captured in an error handler. So... looking for a NO_DATA_FOUND exception will not work because there isn't one.
Check in the application errors (session > session state > errors):


That should guide you in the right direction

I have already checked this, but it didn’t help much. The error is still showing the same message with limited details.
APEX - Error processing process. - Contact your application administrator. ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1473 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR", line 1508

Are you able to turn on debug to level 9 when that error occurs ? the debug must show something.

Yes, turned on the debug-9 but not showing much details.

What does "not much details" mean ? Do you see the error in the debug ? What is happening right before the error - something must be causing the error, debug should show what is erroring out.
If you want to create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com , I'm happy to take a look. Use workspace SO_HELP, username/pwd SO_79104475/SO_79104475
